# PDE exercise recomendation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

I'm looking for exercises concerning parabollic and hyperbollic equations so I can practice for a class. My background is Evans chapter 6 and 7 regarding these topics and I've already checked the problems section in that book.

I'm also interested in exercises on fundamental solutions. We studied this topic from Mitrea's book.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help me!

Comment: Did you do all of the problems in chapters 6 and 7 in Evans?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for more exercises to practice.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your answers are correct? How did you check your work?